# If a datagam is received by a udp client can we trust the data integrity?

Tags: c#, udp

Since UDP is a connection less protocol so we know there is no guarantee that data will be received by a receiver. But if the datagram is received, is it possible that data is partly /fully corrupt ?

UDP header also contains CRC, so this makes me feel that in case datagram is received the data would be   reliable ? Is that correct or not ?

To more elaborate the problem I send the data from Java udp server like

```
// Sending in Java
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
    //buf is a String.getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, 4446);
//socket is DatagramSocket in Java
socket.send(packet);
```

and get data in C# client like this

```
       // client  is UdpClient of C#
       Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);                        
       strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

I am not manipulating CRC myself , at the receiver end I get the same data that was sent in buf, SO how do I check the CRC here, given I have an array of byte data.. ? or assume it would be correct (I can live with those extreme cases where CRC would match ie CRC and data are magically corrupt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trust that the datagram is intact if its checksum (not technically a CRC) is correct, but that doesn't mean you can trust the data.  There's nothing magic about the checksum formula, so a process that altered the data could merely recalculate the checksum and you'd never know.

Comment: I have further elaborated my question, I receive an array of bytes just as I send them from java. I am not myself putting any crc. BUt I do not know how to check it given the byte[]

Comment: You don't have to verify the checksum.  It will be verified for you at one several levels.  If `UdpClient.Receive()` returns a datagram, you can assume the checksum matches that datagram content.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming functioning hardware, OS and IP stack, single-packet integrity is assured by IP checksums.

I mention this assumptions, as I have seen many cases of IP checksumming being turned off (in the sense of allways returning "OK") for performance reasons, or as an implementation defect: Some NICs can do checksums in hardware, but bad or wrong driver parameters can ruin your day.

Comment: I receive a byte[] in the receive call, but these bytes only contain data, should I match the crc myself ? or assume byte[] is correct

Comment: You only get the payload of the packet, not the packet itself (you would need a `raw`socket for that), and I think you should just use it as-is, but build some resiliency into your app in case something happens.

Answer (score 0):

By default OS rejects packets with invalid checksum. This mean you will receive less bad packets than proper ones. But you can configure socket to allow partial/corrupted packets to be propagated to userspace.

Comment: Sorry I got confused with the statement, "This mean you will receive less bad packets than proper ones" ? Are you saying I will only get good packets at application layer ?

Comment: I mean you will get only those packets that has passed checksum verification. Of course packets like that might not be the same as those sent by remote end, but you will get rid of most part of those that were corrupted during transport due to natural reasons.